# New line character in output file

Tags: javascript, string, text-files, newline

When I try to write a string with multiple lines to an output text file the newline chars are not preserved and all the content is printed on one single line.

In the specific I have a button with a listener on click with associated this function:

```
function (e) {
    this.downloadButton.setAttribute("download", "output.txt");
    var textToSend = string1+"\r\n"+string2+"\r\n"+string3;
    this.downloadButton.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + textToSend);
}
```

The file correctly downloaded, but string1, string2 and string3 are on the same line.

Any suggestion?

Comment: which browser and os are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may need to encode your data, which you can do with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Try this:

```
var textToSend = string1+"\r\n"+string2+"\r\n"+string3;
textToSend = encodeURIComponent(textToSend);
this.downloadButton.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + textToSend)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `encodeURIComponent()`. See working example below.

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById('download');
var textToSend = encodeURIComponent("string1\r\nstring2\r\nstring3");
downloadButton.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + textToSend);
```

```html
<a id="download" download="output.txt">Download</a>
```